# Java constant objects and fields

Tags: java, object, static, constants, final

I want to make a file, which is called ObjectsInfos.java
It has too many objects' info.
Which way is the best to implement the problem? Which one is the most effective?
Singleton ? Inheritance? ..?

Thanks for helping.

.. Edit. The informations will be added later. So I must write the informations to a new java file.

```
//ObjectsInfos.java
    public class ObjectsInfos{

         public class Object1Info{
              static final int attr1 = 1;
              static final int attr2 = 5;
         }

         public class Object2Info{
              static final int attr1 = 3;
              static final int attr2 = 6;
         }
    }
    ---------------------------
    //Another java class
        static void main(){
            myGenericMethod(ObjectsInfos.Object1Info.attr1, ObjectsInfos.Object1Info.attr2);
            myGenericMethod(ObjectsInfos.Object2Info.attr1, ObjectsInfos.Object2Info.attr2);
        }
```

Comment: "It has too many objects" How did you determine this was the case?

Comment: Also your code looks... confusing at best.

Comment: It is not clear, what exactly you want to achieve. Why would you want to define Object1 and Object2 when they only have static final attributes? You could those attributes directly in ObjectsInfo.

Comment: There are no objects at all in your code, just classes...

Comment: "Which way is the best to implement the problem?" - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I mean, in somewhere i use the object's. And i just want to the infos of the objects

Comment: But what is your problem? What makes you think you have "too many objects"? It is super unclear what you are asking.

Comment: i wonder, if my implementation is okay and its effective

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you are looking for an `enum`.

```
public enum ObjectsInfos{
    Object1Info(1,5),
    Object2Info(3,6);
    private final int attr1;
    private final int attr2;

    ObjectsInfos(int attr1, int attr2) {
        this.attr1 = attr1;
        this.attr2 = attr2;
    }

    public int getAttr1() {
        return attr1;
    }

    public int getAttr2() {
        return attr2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also define a set of enumerations inside of a class. For example if you think about food and its categories:

```
public class Food {

    private Food() {
    }

    enum Fruit {
        BANANA,
        ORANGE
    }

    enum Vegetable {
        CARROT,
        LETTUCE
    }

    enum Cereal {
        CORN,
        WHEAT
    }

    enum Meat {
        COW,
        PORK
    }

    enum Sauce {
        TOMATOE,
        MUSTARD
    }
}
```

Enums are a robust alternative to the simple `String` or `int` constants. They offer you some methods out of the box like `values` or `valueOf` which can be very convenient and type safety on top of it (which you will not get with just `ints`).

Here is a simple example on how you can use the above enumeration:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FoodMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isCereal("bla"));
        System.out.println(isCereal("wheat"));
        Stream.of(Food.Fruit.values()).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static boolean isCereal(String cereal) {
        return Arrays.stream(Food.Cereal.values()).anyMatch(c -> c.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(cereal));
    }
}
```